# "where" query using linq xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq

been taxing my brain trying to figure out how to perform a linq xml query.

i'd like the query to return a list of all the "product" items where the category/name = "First Category" in the following xml

```
<catalog>
  <category>
    <name>First Category</name>
    <order>0</order>
    <product>
      <name>First Product</name>
      <order>0</order>
    </product>
    <product>
      <name>3 Product</name>
      <order>2</order>
    </product>
    <product>
      <name>2 Product</name>
      <order>1</order>
    </product>
  </category>
</catalog>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like so:

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    var qry = from cat in doc.Root.Elements("category")
              where (string)cat.Element("name") == "First Category"
              from prod in cat.Elements("product")
              select prod;
```

or perhaps with an anonymous type too:

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    var qry = from cat in doc.Root.Elements("category")
              where (string)cat.Element("name") == "First Category"
              from prod in cat.Elements("product")
              select new
              {
                  Name = (string)prod.Element("name"),
                  Order = (int)prod.Element("order")
              };
    foreach (var prod in qry)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", prod.Order, prod.Name);
    }
```

Comment: There would seem to be only one `category` with name *First Category*, so `Single` is probably more appropiate here.

Comment: I think it is safe to assume that this is a fragment from a larger xml block, otherwise the filtering itself is redundant. In which case you cannot say how many categories there are with given names...

Comment: In various UI frameworks, name implies uniqueness. I could probably think of several other examples. I don't think there's much point arguing over what is a rather subjective issue anyway.

Comment: I agree, this is mainly conjecture. The OP has both solutions anyway, so they can choose whichever. :)

Comment: I take it the explicit conversion to `string` won't complain if `Element` returns null?

Comment: thanks guys.  just to clear it up, name is unique in this case. 
but i have other similar scenarios where it isnt unique. So both are awesome :D

Comment: @sf: No problem. And yeah, Where/Single will often be interchangeable, though the latter is generally more efficient when applicable.

Comment: @Noldorin - indeed; using a cast (instead of .Value) means it doesn't throw if null (missing)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
        string xml = @"your XML";

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        var products = from category in doc.Element("catalog").Elements("category")
                       where category.Element("name").Value == "First Category"
                       from product in category.Elements("product")
                       select new
                       {
                           Name = product.Element("name").Value,
                           Order = product.Element("order").Value
                       };
        foreach (var item in products)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} Order: {1}", item.Name, item.Order);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `Single` extension method here. Try the following:

```
var category = doc.RootNode.Elements("category").Single(
    c => c.Attribute("name").Value == "First Category");
var products = category.Elements("product");
```

Note that this assumes you only have one category with name "First Category". If you possibly have more, I recommend using Marc's solution; otherwise, this should be the more appropiate/efficient solution. Also, this will throw an exception if any `category` node doesn't have a `name` child node. Otherwise, it should do exactly what you want.

Comment: Now this is baffling me. This answer is fully correct, given the (IMO fair) assumption that the OP is only looking for one category called "First Category"...

Comment: I agree it should work (athough the attribute stuff could be simpler, and you run the risk of throwing exceptions if any of the elements/attributes are missing); +1 here... I don't know why, but all the original answers on this question got downvotes.

Comment: @Marc: Cheers. And yeah, I should probably add the caveat for null attribute objects, though if `Name` is guaranteed to exist... I've only downvoted MrTortoise's answer now. (I changed yours to an upvote once I reread the question and your answer properly!)